# Decide if $b_n := \left(-1+\frac 1 {n^2}\right)^n$ converges

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I want to show if the sequence $b _n := \left(-1+\frac 1 {n^2}\right)^n$
is convergent or not, but im stuck finding a Limit to conclue with Epsilon-test

Comment: Does not converge. It oscillates in $(-1;\;1)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\left(-1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n=(-1)^n\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n$$

and from Bernoulli's Inequality we have

$$1-\frac1n\le \left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\le 1$$

Comment: thanks, nice trick !

Comment: @gt6989b Thank you.  Much appreciative.

Comment: @masterpi Thank you.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(-1+\frac 1 {n^2}\right)^n=\left(\frac 1 {n}+1\right)^n\left(\frac 1 {n}-1\right)^n=(-1)^n\left(\frac 1 {n}+1\right)^n\left(1-\frac 1 {n}\right)^n$$

but, by the Fundamental Limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1 {n}\right)^n=e$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac 1 {n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to -\infty}\left(1+\frac 1 {n}\right)^{-n}=e^{-1}$$